# Build UPC codes from existing data - keep the leading zeros and eliminate the space between the numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I am building UPC codes using data imported into Excel. When copying this data over to a new column to create the UPC codes, I need to keep the leading 0's but eliminate the spaces between the columns. For example, this 0000 007 1600 to 00000071600.

I have tried changing the column to text for the 0's (which seems to work) and using Find/Replace to find the spaces and eliminate them (which doesn't work).

Per someone's recommendation, I opened the Excel file in notes, copied it into a new excel sheet, and used the following formula: =SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","#",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")))))," ","")

Per this last step, when I save the EXCEL file and reopen it, the formula doesn't save and I lose my leading zeros.

Any suggestions on another way to do this, please? Thank you for your time.

---

I'm using Microsoft Office Home and Student 2019

Comment: Not sure I understand. If `A1` contains e.g. 0000 007 1600 then `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")` returns 00000071600, as per your requirements. But then I'm not sure what you mean by "eliminate the spaces between the columns"? Is 0000 007 1600 not contained within a single cell?

Comment: @JosWoolley Thank you for your response. That formula worked. The issue now is when I save the file as a csv then reopen the file, the leading zero's aren't there. I have to change everything back to text, delete the column, and redo the formula in a new column. (I need to email the file to a computer at a different location so I can run a macro and export the data.)

Comment: Do not **Open** the csv file. To avoid that problem, you must **import** the csv file using either Power Query or the legacy import wizard.  If you do that, you will have an opportunity to  designate that column as Text, and the leading zero's will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

After saving the csv file, change the file extension to .txt
Then open the file using Data > Data Tools > Text to columns, setting the separator as comma and marking the UPC column as Text (rather than General or Number).

Alternatively, use Power Query to load the csv file, via Data > Get & Transform Data > From Text/CSV. Again, mark the UPC column as Text.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'm trying them out now.